How to estimate TFLOPS for calculation in Quantum Espresso?
My question is related to this. But I am more interested in knowing if there is a way to estimate computational requirements in terms of TFLOPS.
I was talking to someone who works in hardware design, and he suggested that knowing the number of TFLOPS I would be able to figure out how much resources I should requisition as well as the computation time.
A little bit of googling revealed that in code optimization this dark art is called 'profiling'. I often use Quantum Espresso in my work and I have read the documentation section explaining time reports. Nevertheless are there tools to profile a QE calculation in advance, especially in TFLOPS?
